# Animate some rows or columns of a matrix in powerpoint

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

In microsoft-powerpoint, i have a matrix, I want to animate some elements, or consider some rows or columns of it to move that part to another matrix. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that by "matrix" you mean "table", you could create one table and leave the cells to be animated as blanks, then create another identical table with the cells to be animated filled in and the other cells left blank (and with their backgrounds set to unfilled.)

OR

Insert the table, fill it in completely, format it to taste.
Then move it off the slide
Copy it
Paste Special and choose Picture (Enanced Metafile).

Ungroup the newly pasted table.
Ungroup it again.

Now you can choose the shapes you want to animate, group them and apply animation to the group.